Scrolling in terminal lags direction change by one scroll?
I am working on Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS. This problem has only popped up in terminal and in the "Test Your Settings" section of the "Mouse & Touchpad" menu in Settings.
Basically, whenever I am scrolling in terminal, and switch directions, the window scrolls one more time in the direction I was previously scrolling. I.e., I am scrolling down, stop scrolling down and begin to scroll up, and the window scrolls down one more time before scrolling up. Also, after this has happened, if I hover off the terminal window with my mouse, the window jumps one scroll, to where it would be had the erroneous scroll not happened.
I have tried installing and running both configurations of imwheel as listed in the answers on this post: Mouse wheel scrolling ignores first scroll
Neither worked for me. I have also made sure all my drivers are up to date. This bug is not present scrolling in most other applications like firefox, nor is it present when using the Windows partition on the same machine with the same mouse. This has been driving me crazy, any suggestions would be appreciated.
